# datetimecontrol access error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web-part

I have a SharePoint `DateTimeControl` in a page which was deployed as a webpart and working on the first server. Then I had to move the solution to another farm. Now I got the error when I click on the calendar icon in my webpart. I am the Farm admin. Any idea why this happens?

[image]

the ULS log is Access denide:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_WebTemplate()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_WebTemplateConfiguration()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.InitJs_Register(Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, Boolean injectNoDefer, Boolean controlRegistration, Boolean loadInlineLast, Boolean ignoreFileNotFound)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, String uiVersion, String ctag)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Control ctrl, Page page, String strKey, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.GetOnDemandScriptKey(String strKey, String strFile, Boolean registerDependencies, Control ctrl, Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Control ctrl, Page page, String strKey, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterStringsJsIfNecessary(String strFile, Page page)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, Boolean injectNoDefer, Boolean controlRegistration, Boolean loadInlineLast, Boolean ignoreFileNotFound)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Control ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String language, String uiVersion, String ctag)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Control ctrl, Page page, String strKey, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterOnDemand(Control ctrl, Page page, String strFile, Boolean localizable)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)    
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Comment: have you checked your ULS logs ? can you share some on the log output?

Comment: @MarceloEspinosa its mostly access denied. I dont know which access I need. My account is administrator and I need normal user to access it.

Comment: and I have two webparts in the same page which both have the same problem with the calendar

Comment: Can you please post markup of your DateTimeControl in  webpart?

Comment: Try with adding date time control like this, <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="datetimeCntrl" runat="server" CalendarImageUrl="/_layouts/images/calendar.gif" DateOnly="true" DatePickerFrameUrl=<%
$SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/iframe.aspx %> />

Comment: @VishalMPatil thanks :) with DatePickerFrameUrl it works. But before it was working without it!

Comment: @VishalMPatil when I add SPUrl and it through error as it is not recognized but with the absolute Url it works!